# datadog log processing: how to unescape nested json

Tags: logstash-grok, datadog

I'm sending json formatted logs messages to datadog:

```
  "Headers": {
    "Content-Type": [
      "application/json"
    ]
  },
  "Method": "POST",
  "Body": "{\"test\": 1234, \"test2\": {\"test3\": 1245}}",
  "URL": "https://test",
  "Host": "test",
  "UserAgent": ""
}
```

The issue is with the field `Body`. I want datadog to pick this up as json so it's parsed. So I'm looking into log pipelines and in particular the `grok` processor to preprocess the log message and unescape the `Body` field.

`%{data::json}` as a parsing rule works but doesn't unescape Body. I tried stuff like: `%{data::json{source => "Body" target => "Body"}}` but datadog marks the rule as invalid.

1. Is there a better way to achieve the unescaping in datadog?
2. How can I create a valid grok rule for datadog that unescapes the Body field?